# Using ${ } in commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

why does this not work?

```
ls -l ${which cal}
```

I'm assuming ${} executes the command inside of it and puts it into a variable that the previous command can then use. Trying to learn the minutia of bash

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect

Comment: `${which cal}` would try to expand a variable named `which cal`, but that is not a valid name.

Comment: `${ }` does variable expansion; `$( )` does command substitution; `$(( ))` does arithmetic expansion. You generally should put double-quotes around it to avoid weird parsing of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

```
ls -l $(which cal)
```